# Which is the better way to show dynamic radio buttons in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose my javascript called server(AJAX call) and then got server response with an array of data : `dataArray`.

the number of data in the `dataArray` will be either 1 or 2 or 3, that's **no more than 3**.

I would like to show the data as radio button selections. Since the number of data is dynamic(1 or 2 or 3), so I should show radio buttons dynamically.

I came up with two ways to do this:

**1st way:** have three radio buttons in the HTML:

```
<div id="my-radio-btns">
   <input id="data0" type="radio" name="datas" value="0"><label for="data0"></label>
   <input id="data1" type="radio" name="datas" value="1"><label for="data1"></label>
   <input id="data2" type="radio" name="datas" value="2"><label for="data2"></label>
</div>
```

then, hide and show certain number of the above radio buttons based on the number of data in the `dataArray`.

**2nd way:** use javascript to append radio button HTML strings:

```
for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++){

     $('#my-radio-btns').append("<input id='data"+i+"type='radio' name='datas' value="+i+"> <label for='data"+i+"></label>");

}
```

I am wondering, which way is better?

Comment: I vote for the first, because when creating them dynamically on runtime you will have to keep them in a global variable if you want to read their values persisted upon resubmitting. Better keep them hidden in page and when reading read only the visible ones.

Comment: I'm curious about this too, and what better way than to find the answer by testing? I suggest you make a test on jsperf.com and post a link here.

Comment: *Better* in terms of **what**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already have a couple of solutions it really comes down to a discussion on the merits of each.

With the first approach:

- You don't have to create any markup as it's already there.
- If you are hiding these elements then you can use display:none or
  visibility:hidden, the latter will reserve the space in the page
  layout such that there is no shifting of elements as you display them.
- If your number of expected elements increase, what's so bad about adding another radio
  button to the markup?

The second approach:

- Allows you to simply increase the number of radio buttons displayed by increasing the number of data elements in the array.
- It probably won't sway your desicion much, as it looks like your DOM
  manipulation is quite minimal, but one of the most expensive
  operations in jquery is modifying the DOM. Just something to think about.

Also, may I suggest a little enhancement to the second code sample:

```
var markup = "";
for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++){
    markup += "<input id='data"+i+"type='radio' name='datas' value="+i+"> <label for='data"+i+"></label>";
}

$('#my-radio-btns').append(markup);
```

Prevents multiple lookups of the my-radio-btns element - won't make a huge amount of difference over the space of 3 elements but if you increase this is may start of add up.

Comment: I finally used the first way, but I prefer your suggestion of the code for the second approach. THank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the second, since it's more scalable in terms of different numbers of radio buttons. Although you say it will never be more than 3, why force that restriction if you can avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is a big "it depends". But without any prior knowledge of your application details (i.e. assuming the business requirements will never change), I say "go with your gut". That is, which one do find easier to understand/use in the context of the rest of your code?

Personally, I would go with your first solution, because it more cleanly separates out the HTML logic from the Javascript logic.

But there are a other competing ideas (extensibility, DOM clutter, etc...) that might sway you to use one method or the other.

Answer (score 0):

If there'll ever be a maximum of 3 radio buttons, I'd recommend going with the first option. It's the simplest. If you had to deal with *n* radio buttons then a more sophisticated solution may be warranted.

Form processing will be a whole lot easier as you won't have to do any pre-submit client-side or post-submit server-side processing of dynamically-generated radio buttons.

Remember: **K.I.S.S. - Keep It Simple, Stupid**